# why does this code only register certain collisions and not all?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

Hi i have a code for a game where there are multiple fruits falling from the sky and the frog at the bottom has to try and catch them. When he catches one the score goes up. This only happens when the frog collides with some of the fruit and not all of them. And the score randomly starts increasing unstoppably for no reason after a certain point.  Here is most of the code as im not sure where the error would be :

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *
from math import fabs
######### constants ##########
jumpvel=20
fallingspeed=1
running= True
blue= [129,183 ,253]
pink=[255,174,201]
textcolour= [255,255,255]
x=700//2
y=1000//2
score=0

thingylist= ['fruit1.bmp','fruit2.bmp','fruit3.bmp','fruit4.bmp','fruit5.bmp','fruit1.bmp','fruit2.bmp','fruit3.bmp','fruit4.bmp','fruit5.bmp','naughty1.bmp','naughty2.bmp','naughty3.bmp',]
all_things=[]
for i in range (12):
    new_thing_image=pygame.image.load(thingylist[(random.randrange(0,12))])
    new_thing_image.set_colorkey(pink)
    new_thing_rect=new_thing_image.get_rect()
    new_thing_rect.x=random.randrange(0,950)
    new_thing_rect.y=-random.randrange(50,500)
    all_things.append([new_thing_image,new_thing_rect])

def checkCollision (frog_rect,all_things,score):
    collides_with=None
    for thing_image, thing_rect in all_things:
        if frog_rect.colliderect(thing_rect):
            collides_with=True
    if collides_with == True:
        score= score+100
    return collides_with,score

######## initialising screen#########        
pygame.init()
gamedisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600)) #making the screen
pygame.display.set_caption('frog')
clock=pygame.time.Clock()# frames per second
bg=pygame.image.load('actual clouds.bmp').convert()


############ initialising sprites##############
frog= pygame.image.load('actual frog.bmp')
frog.set_colorkey(blue)
frog_rect=frog.get_rect()
frog_rect.centerx=(x)
frog_rect.centery=(y)

##########drawing things#############
def drawThings (all_things):
    for item in all_things:
        new_thing_image, new_thing_rect= item
        gamedisplay.blit(new_thing_image, (new_thing_rect.x, new_thing_rect.y))

#########update display function###########
def update(x,y,all_things,score):
    gamedisplay.blit(bg,[0,0])
    gamedisplay.blit(frog,(x,y))
    for thing in range (len(all_things)):
        new_thing_rect=all_things[i][1]
        #thing_rect.y=thing_rect.y+fallingspeed
        new_thing_rect.y+= fallingspeed
    drawThings(all_things)
    label=font.render("score "+ str(score) ,1,textcolour)
    gamedisplay.blit(label,(750,10))
    gamedisplay.blit(heart1,(750,50))
    gamedisplay.blit(heart2,(850,50))
    gamedisplay.blit(heart2,(800,50))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(50)

while running == True:
    gamedisplay.blit(bg,[0,0])
    gamedisplay.blit(frog,(x,y))
    drawThings(all_things)
    label=font.render("score "+ str(score) ,1,textcolour)
    gamedisplay.blit(label,(750,10))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.event.pump()
    key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for item in all_things:
        new_thing_image, new_thing_rect= item
        new_thing_rect.y+= fallingspeed
        if new_thing_rect.y >450:
            new_thing_rect.x=random.randrange(0,950)
            new_thing_rect.y=-random.randrange(50,500)
    ############collision detection##########
    detect,score =checkCollision (frog_rect, all_things,score)

    update(x,y,all_things,score)
```

The score should increase every time it collides with any of the falling friuts not just certain ones and not just start increasing randomly non-stop. Any help would be appreciated thankyou !

Comment: Where is `frog_rect` being updated?  Does the frog move?  The collision function looks ok (except you only score once for possible multiple collisions).

Comment: @Kingsley the frog is being updates in the update function : gamedisplay.blit(frog,(x,y)) but im not sure about frog_rect.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: The `gamedisplay.blit(frog,(x,y))` is only painting the frog bitmap to the screen at `(x, y)`.  The `frog_rect` needs to be updated with any change in the frog co-ordinates for collision to work.  Is this happening?  I would have expected the frog to be drawn like: `gamedisplay.blit( frog, ( frog_rect.centerx, frog_rect.centery ) )`, because the (centred) co-ordinates are set like this in initialisation of `frog_rect`.

Comment: @Kingsley i have these lines in my code therefore updating y and x is the same as frog_rect.centerx ??????                  frog= pygame.image.load('actual frog.bmp')
frog.set_colorkey(blue)
frog_rect=frog.get_rect()
frog_rect.centerx=(x)
frog_rect.centery=(y)

Comment: No, it does not work like that.  You need to either update the `frog_rect` whenever `x` and `y` change, or maintain the sprite's position with only `frog_rect`.  The core of the problem is you're using one set of co-ordinates for the sprite's on-screen position, and another set for the collision rectangle (which is never updated, except initially).

Comment: @Kingsley how would you do that? because what I have done  seems to have fixed the collision detection problem but the score still keeps randomly going up unstoppably, therefore i don’t know if i’ve done it right.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code snippet - which does not include the frog-position updating code, I would guess that the problems of:

- Score randomly increasing
- Collisions not always working

Are caused by the collision rectangle being defined once for the frog's starting position, but then never being updated with changes in the frog's position.

```
############ initialising sprites##############
frog= pygame.image.load('actual frog.bmp')
frog.set_colorkey(blue)
frog_rect=frog.get_rect()
frog_rect.centerx=(x)       # <-- rect only ever updated here!
frog_rect.centery=(y)
```

This would lead to the described symptoms, since scoring-objects (fruit?) falling through the collision rectangle would add to the score (seemingly randomly), and when the frog was still over it's original position, collision would work perfectly.  If the frog was partially over the rect it would somewhat work, and not at all once the frog moved away that start-position rect.

The solution to the problem is to update the co-ordinates of the rectangle `frog_rect` whenever the `x` & `y` of the frog's position is updated.  This can be achieved by setting the `frog_rect.centerx` and `frog_rect.centery` inside the `update()` function:

```
def update(x, y, all_things, score ):
    frog_rect.x = x
    frog_rect.y = y
```

The frog's rect is initialised with `.centerx`, `.centery` co-ordinates, but the frog is draw at `x,y`, so the collision rect begins a little off-centre too.  Thus it would be best to update the initialisation function as well:

```
frog_rect=frog.get_rect()
frog_rect.x = x
frog_rect.y = y
```